# Why does the Gaussian integral need a special form?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

This is probably a really easy question, but I was just trying to work out the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) and I must be wrong, but I am not sure where I am wrong...

If $\frac{\delta}{\delta x} e^{-x^2} = -2xe^{-x^2}$ then it should mean that we can take the integral of the same expression by just reversing the process. This implies that to take the integral instead of the derivative, I would divide by the derivative of the exponent...

$$
\int -2xe^{-x^2} = e^{-x^2} \implies \int e^{-x^2} = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{-2x}
$$

But this doesn't evaluate to $\sqrt{\pi}$ as the famous result does, so I must have gotten something really wrong somewhere. Where have I gone wrong? Why does this integral need such a special derivation different than a normal integral (as it does in the link above).

I started doing this because I thought I would learn why this integral is special because I thought it would become obvious when I tried to do it, but its not obvious to me

Comment: dividing by the derivative of the exponent doesn't work. Try calculating the derivative $\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{-2x}$, and see whether or not you recover $e^{-x^2}$. i.e it is NOT true that $\int e^{f(x)}\, dx = \dfrac{e^{f(x)}}{f'(x)}$ (if you differentiate the RHS, you have to use the quotient rule). What is true is that (as you discovered correctly in the beginning) $\int f'(x)e^{f(x)}\, dx = e^{f(x)}$

Comment: peek-a-boo is almost correct: there is also that little constant: $$\int f'(x) e^{f(x)}\, dx = e^{f(x)} + C$$It may seem trivial, but failure to realize that the immediate antiderivative you've found is not the only one will occasionally cause you much pain.